# check if string contains number larger than a number

Tags: java, string, type-conversion

i have a String in my app that receive by sms always changing and sometimes is a number with 2 decimal places and sometime without decimal places like below :

```
String sms = "12.02";
String sms = "105";
```

how can i Comparison number inside the String for example if larger than 5 do something in app ??

the decimal places not important

sorry for my poor language

Comment: you mean greater than 5? or string length larger than 5 without decimals ?

Comment: yes larger than 5 without decimals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Float.valueOf`. Something like this:

```
if (Float.valueOf(sms)>5){
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the decimal places are not important, you could do something like this:

```
String sms = "12.02";
double d = Double.parseDouble(sms); // 12.02 [approximately]
int i = (int) d; // 12

if (i > 5) {
    // do whatever
}
```

Comment: thanks but on this method if the number doesn't have decimal places app will crash

Comment: Whether or not the number has decimal places doesn't affect the answer. However, I did notice that I wrote `Double d` when I should have written `double d`, so perhaps that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        if (Double.parseDouble(sms) > 5) {
                // do something
        }
    }
     catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            Log.e("Invalid Number",e.toString());
        }
```